# Using "any" as a value in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function like this (in the context of AWS/SNS):

```
def validate(message, topic=None):
    if topic == any or topic == message.topic:
        accept()
    else:
        reject()
    ...
```

The value `any` in the condition is actually the built-in function [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). But here I'm not using it for its designed purpose, but as a constant, to indicate that any topic would be accepted without colliding with any possible existing topic value (which are strings).

I have the feeling this is not a good idea, but I can't find a good reason why it isn't. Also, I've tried googling this, but "any" is too common a word and I haven't had luck finding a discussion about this.

Is this right, wrong, pythonic?

Comment: I think passing a string is more safe.

Comment: That being said, if you want to proceed, then you should use `is`. But a problem is, that people might get the idea that they can pass any function (not *the* any function :). Or what if someone passes a partial function?

Comment: What about simply `if topic or ...`?

Comment: Use `any_` instead? [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Comment: @landogardner `if topic is None or ...` seems more appropriate

Comment: But `topic == any` will always return False. Or are you shadowing `any` name?

Comment: @Caleth `if topic is not None or ...` surely?

Comment: If any topic (other than `None`) is to be accepted, what is the purpose of checking its value? Just use it after verifying that it isn't `None`. The only thing I can imagine is that you have a specific set of valid topics that you want `topic` to belong to: `if topic in valid_topics or topic == message.topic` (where `message.topic` is assumed to *not* necessarily be a member of `valid_topics`).

Comment: When you call `validate(message)` do you expect it to reject *all* messages? I don't, the default parameter of `None` for `topic` indicates to not filter on `message.topic`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies. @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I meant to write `topic is any`. @Laszlowaty, again I meant `topic is any`, I don't want to edit the question to keep the comments understandable. @Caleth, I intended the user to be explicit with the topic, so the default of None would meant just that: "valid topics? none."

After all the comments I think that the main drawback would be confusion. Being AWS and knowing that all valid topics start with `arn:aws:sns:` I think the right way is to use a special string constant, as @WillemVanOnsem suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but using `any` as value is wrong unless it's correct to call `validate` with `any` as second parameter:

```
validate(msg, any)
```

To check if `topic` is not `None` use `topic is not None`.

```
def validate(message, topic=None):
    if topic is not None or topic == message.topic:
        accept()
    else:
        reject()
    ...
```

It's possible that you want `and` instead `or`.